# Load class within Jar file and get it's path

Tags: java, plugins, jar, classloader, urlclassloader

I know there are already a lot similar questions here, but I couldn't get any smarter form them. I want to load a class inside a jar file, at this point this is no problem, but when I want to pass the path to my own ClassLoader it throws an exception it cannot find the class. Is it possible to load a class inside a jar using an absolute path? For instance,
`Class cls = loader.loadClass(/path/MyPlugin.jar/MyPlugin.class);`

But when I do this:

```
File test = new File("path/plugins/MyPlugin.jar/MyPlugin.class");
System.out.println(test.exists());
```

It prints out false. I tried using `MyPlugin.jar!/MyPlugin.class` or `MyPlugin.jar.jar!MyPlugin.class` which i've seen sometimes on the web, even though i don't really know what it means...

When I do this it finds the class:

```
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { "path/plugins/MyPlugin.jar" });
Class cl = loader.loadClass("MyPlugin");
```

But now, how can I receive the path? Something like `URL url = cl.getResource("MyPlugin");` (which gives back a null)

Comment: Weak guess: Have you tried `cl.getResource()`, instead of `cls.getResource();` ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, just a typing mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain URLs to classpath resources using [ClassLoader.getResources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29). To find a jar with specific class, you may use the following

```
URL url = classLoader.getResource("com/example/SomeClass.class");
JarURLConnection connection = (JarURLConnection) url.openConnection();
JarFile file = connection.getJarFile();
String jarPath = file.getName();
```

where `classLoader` is any classloader capable of finding the class you want to load. If the jar is a part of your application's classpath, you may use system classloader:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassloader();
```

Otherwise, you need to know the jar file location beforehand, and create an instance of `URLClassLoader`, passing the jar in the constructor:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL("path/to/the/jar/file.jar")});
```

and then use it to load your class.

Comment: I tried it, even though i don't know if i got it right. How would this look like in practice?

Comment: On second thought, manual string manipulation is not necessary. See my edit.

Comment: Sorry I'm totally new here. What does classloader refer to? So example is actually a jar called example.jar?

Comment: Well... if you know the class name and the jar location, you can use the approach from the second part of my answer. If you have the class already loaded, you can use the suggestion from the first part. Otherwise, I see no way to do it; you cannot load the class if it's not on the classpath and you don't know what jar(s) contain its definition.

Comment: Ahh, I see... Well, I'm not aware of any way to use `File`-based API to address jar content, sorry. Using `File` as the only classpath element type seems unnecessarily limiting, though. Is the classloader under your controll? Or, if you're fine with hackish solution, perhaps it has the constructor that allows specifying parent classloader? You could inject the `URLClassLoader` and let you have you `PluginClassLoader` delegate loading to it.

Comment: How come it says this path doesn't exist? `URL url = cl.getResource("MyPlugin.class"); // output: "jar:file:/.../plugins/MyPlugin.jar!/MyPlugin.class"` `System.out.println(new File(url.toString()).exists()); // output: false`

Comment: Because when i do this: `ClassLoader cl = new PluginClassLoader(new File("jar:file:/.../MyPlugin.jar!/"));` `Class c = cl.loadClass("MyPlugin.class");` I get a `FileNotFoundException: jar:file:/.../MyPlugin.jar!/MyPlugin.class (No such file or directory)` ...?

Comment: Well, that's because while the path exists, `File` API is not jar-aware. It cannot look inside the jar and see that there is indeed `MyPlugin.class` file. I'm afraid you cannot do it without changing `PluginClassLoader`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a file in your jar file you have to put it in the same directory as the class files are.

For example if Main.class is in bin/my/pkg/Main.class you can store your MyPlugin.class in the same directory (bin/my/pkg/MyPlugin.class) and then, if you want to access that file use

```
URL url = Main.getResource("MyPlugin.class");
```

Which uses the location of Main.class in your project as root.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's not quite right. Jar file needs to be on the classpath. Placing *the jar* on the classpath does not make it part of the classpath.

Comment: Getting an error when trying this `URL url = PluginTest.getResource("MyPlugin.class");`. And receiving a null when trying this: `URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("MyPlugin.class");`

Comment: Are you aware that you need to use fully qualified name, with `/` in place of dots?

Comment: So i need to do this "MyPlugin/class"?

Comment: Assuming you plugin is `com.example.MyPlugin`, you need `com/example/MyPlugin.class`. If it's in the default package, `MyPlugin.class` indeed should do.