# Maven - Identifying the source pom file of a dependency

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I have a situation where in my EAR file I have 'N' number of JAR files[modules] present. In these JAR files, there are certain artifacts which are duplicate. By duplicate, I mean the artifact name is same but with different versions.

Ex:
adapter-base-59.0-20141219-311675-3.jar
adapter-base-60.0-20141223-678915-68.jar

I would like to get help on how to find the source pom file location for these JAR files.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Deepan

Comment: The source POM file should be in the same location in your local Maven repo for the specific dependency. If you follow the instructions in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594923/load-class-within-jar-file-and-get-its-path) you might find a solution you can use...

Comment: Have you done a `mvn clean` before? These are SNAPSHOT artifacts from a Nexus repository manager ...it looks you have an other problem in your build cause there is a version `59.0-SNAPSHOT` and `60.0-SNAPSHOT` somewhere in your build....

Answer (score 0):

that might be a bit painful but the dependency can be in a parent pom.xml, a transitive dependency or a profile. Profiles can be in a settings.xml as well.

What I would do is execute `mvn dependency:tree` on the pom.xml where the dependencies are copied and then search where it comes from. Then follow that path.

It is a little weird you have the same jar twice with a different version. Usually maven takes the first one (or closest one) it find. So adding the correct version to your pom.xml has a distance of 1, that would always win - any transitive dependency will have a greater distance.
It might be the dependency uses a different groupId and maven cannot detect its the same artifact.

You could also try to open the jar files - maven usually adds some information into the META-INF directory (if you're lucky and the jar was release with the maven-release-plugin).